# How should I identify a user registered using Facebook login?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, oauth, openid, facebook-oauth

I am trying to  register a user to my Web application using the Facebook login feature using Javascript and then pass the user information into my server side of the application, now I have to save the information so I could log in later as this user but it should be done without a password , what should I save  in my application's db instead of the password  in order to authenticate the user is really who he claims to be and not someone else who is trying to bypass my security? First thought was to save the Facebook user ID to authenticate a user,  but it doesn't sound secure at all, is it a good idea or a bad one?  Is there another of performing what I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend following Facebook's OAuth examples at developers.facebook.com.

It's been a while since I've done any OAuth work, but from what I remember, Facebook executes a callback to your server that you specify. When Facebook calls this callback, they provide you with an access token. You can then use this access token to get information about the user (i.e. email, first name, last name).

It's up to you to determine what to do when this callback is called. Perhaps you fetch the user's email, first and last name and automatically create the user an account on your back end if it doesn't exist. If you found a matching account (perhaps via their email) then just log them in (don't need to store any password for the user). I don't believe there is anything to really worry about with this approach because Facebook is providing a unique access token that resembles the user, and then your server is fetching an email based on this access token. The only way someone could crack this is if they got a hold of the access token for the user, which isn't easy (assuming your using SSL).

To determine if someone created an account using Facebook or another approach, I'd create a column under your "user" table which indicates this information.

Comment: Hi Brian thanks for your reply,  I agree with everything you said,  but it's still unclear to me,  I can't save in my db the Facebook user access token because it's changing everytime I re log to Facebook,  so the only constant parameter I get from my request from Facebook is the user ID of the Facebook user,  but I wouldn't want to identify my user using the user ID(let's remember it is instead of the password), I'm am not sure the Facebook user ID is secure enough so I could trust it, because if someone was able to discover users user ID my application users are volunrable.

Comment: Yes, you don't want to store the access token in the database. You need a way of uniquely identifying the user perhaps their email, or as you said their Facebook user ID. I wouldn't make the user ID easy to retrieve, but you should always architect your application so that it is still secure even if unique ID's are discovered.

Comment: The question is, do Facebook protects it's user ID so I can rely on it? If Facebook reveals the user ID in one way or another I am screwed.

Comment: I don't think you would be screwed, because to log in someone would still need a valid access token. They wouldn't be logging in with the Facebook user ID.

Comment: But he still could log on as my application user and to transactions on his behalf / view sensitive information

Comment: That's where I disagree with you, the application should be built so it is still secure if unique ID's are discovered. If it's not built this way, it is insecure in more ways then just with Facebook  OAuth.

Comment: So how do I make It more secure than? How can I authenticate a user logged in via Facebook?

Comment: Facebook is already doing the authentication for you. Once Facebook authenticates, you get an access token for the user. You can use the access token to retrieve an email/user id. Then log the user into your system that has the email/user id. This is secure because Facebook has already performed the authentication, verifying the user's identity.

Comment: But when I authenticate Facebook i do it on the client,  I have to pass to server some identifier to know which user I need to register/log in to and it can not be email address because it is to public,  it has to be some unique protected information, maybe my mistake is doing it on the client? Should I do it on the server?

Comment: I'd recommend doing it on the server. I've never done it through Facebook's JavaScript SDK. If you get an access token from the JavaScript SDK, perhaps you could create a Facebook login end point on your server and send up the access token. Then you can retrieve the sensitive information on the server, and log the user in on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do some research myself because I implemented Facebook login with the Javascript SDK. 
**As of Graph API 2.0, you no longer receive the main ID of a user**, but [a scoped id which is unique per app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading):

> Facebook will begin to issue app-scoped user IDs when people first log
>   into an instance of your app coded against v2.0 of the API. With
>   app-scoped IDs, the ID for the same user will be different between
>   apps.

**Please note that this is backwards compatible**: If you got users through Graph API < 2.0 then they still have the main id.

From a security point of view things changed therefore slightly, as the scoped id seems to be not accessible from outsiders. This is in contrast to the main Facebook id, which is publicly available to anyone.

That being said, I still do not recommend using this new scoped id as a password replacement.

1. Facebook gives no information whether this is a truly random id. Maybe they use some pattern to generate it which could be exploited by a hacker.
2. Facebook says nowhere that this id is secret. It might well be that a public Graph API call returns a list of a user's scoped ids.
3. Even if the id is unique and secret, you still store it as plain text in your database, meaning that everyone with access to the db can steal the user's identity. Compare this with a salted password hash.

Comment: Whether or not the id is sequential, hidden, public, etc. does not matter. What matters is how you get it. If you trust the user to send his or her ID, then no, it's completely insecure. However, if the user is provided by Facebook directly or you get it by exchanging an access token (which you should), then using that ID is a perfectly valid way to identify a user.